# Mac doesn't recognize internal microphone

Tags: audio, mojave, microphone

On my Mac the internal microphone suddenly disappeared from devices, it doesn't even appear in the sounds settings, as seen in the attached photo:

[image: sound settings]

[Resetting the PRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) solved it temporally, but then it disappeared again.

- Mac: MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018)
- OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.4 (18E226)